# JavaScript Intellisense

Tags: javascript, ide

Is there an IDE with fully documented base library? I mean objects like "console" and "window"? I want to see a tooltip with description for the object itself and its functions. http://liveweave.com supports this but its not an IDE.

I've checked VS2013 and it only provides intellisense.js files for jquery and few other popular libraries. I've checked WebStorm 8 and it's the same thing.

Seems to be an important feature for beginners. I'm baffled.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  WebStorm does a great job with JavaScript.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA (http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and IntelliJ WebStorm (http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) have some amazing built in Intellisense like features and support 3rd party libraries (where Visual Studio falls short). Try checking the plugins if there is something you don't see built in. There are also NuGet plugins that bring intellisense features to some libraries. As an aside, this question will likely get locked because of how much bias it will generate.

Comment: Probably Intellisense is not the right term to use here. Quick documentation is what I am looking for. This illustrates what I want: http://snag.gy/NgBOe.jpg. Instead I get: http://snag.gy/OCqfm.jpg. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try NetBeans [download](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) under column HTML5 & PHP